# Busca em tabela associativa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

Como posso fazer uma busca em tabela associativa ?
Existe duas entidades, Pessoa e Time. De onde surgi a associativa Pessoa_Time que possui id_pessoa e id_time.

Meu objetivo e listar todos os id_time de um certo id_pessoa

Seguinte erro:

HTTP Status 500 - org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: pessoa_time is not mapped [select t from pessoa_time u where u.id_pessoa = :pPessoa]

**PessoaDAO:**

```
public List<Time> listarmeustimes(Pessoa pessoa) {

        Pessoa resultado = new Pessoa();

        String consulta = "select t from pessoa_time u where u.id_pessoa = :pPessoa";
        Query query = getEm().createQuery(consulta);

        query.setParameter("pPessoa", pessoa.getNomeUsuario());

        List<Time> meustimes = query.getResultList();
        for (Time time : meustimes) {
            System.out.println(time.getNome());

        }
        return meustimes;
    }
```

**PessoaBean:**

```
public void listarmeustimes(){
        getDao().listarmeustimes(getPessoa());  
    }
```

Pessoa Model:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="listaPessoas")
private List<Time> listaTimes;
```

Time Model:

```
@ManyToMany
 @JoinTable(name="Pessoa_Time",joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_time")}, 
 inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_pessoa")})
private List<Pessoa> listaPessoas;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe um erro na sua query.

Observe aqui `where u.id_pessoa = :pPessoa"`. A query espera receber no parâmetro `:pPessoa` o **id** da **Pessoa**, mas você está passando é o **nome** aqui `query.setParameter("pPessoa", pessoa.getNomeUsuario());`

O certo deveria ser `query.setParameter("pPessoa", pessoa.getId());`

Mas como o que você realmente quer é listar todos os times que estão relacionados à uma pessoa, entâo mude sua query para ficar assim `String consulta = "from Time t join t.pessoas p where p.id = :pPessoa";`

E no `setParameter` passe o **id** ao invés do **nome**, assim: `query.setParameter("pPessoa", pessoa.getId());`

Comment: Apresentou o seguinte erro: HTTP Status 500 - org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8 [select * from pessoa_time]

Comment: @RafaelAugusto fiz uma modificação na **consulta**. Editei a resposta. Veja se assim funciona.